# Using nth-child css on dynamic React table

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors

I'm having trouble getting the `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` selectors to take effect in a list of divs.

I'm working in a React app and have a component representing a single item in a collection that renders the following HTML structure:

```
<div className="link-row">
  <div className="link-row-header-container">
    <div className="header-name"></div>
    <div className="header-info"></div>
  </div>
  <div className="link-container">
    <div className="left-inner-container"> //this is the container i'm trying to select  
    </div>
    <div className="right-inner-container">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="link-row-footer-container">
    <span> footer stuff </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a function in an outer component mapping the above component over a collection of data and placing them in a single `<div>` like so:

```
<div> {linkList} </div>
```

I'm trying to alternate the background color of "left-inner-container" in sequences of threes, but I'm consistently getting only a single color across all of them.

Here's my CSS:

```
.left-inner-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: #450037;
}

.left-inner-container:nth-of-type(3n+1) {background-color: #ff5e39;}
.left-inner-container:nth-of-type(3n+2) {background-color: #00d2d1;}
.left-inner-container:nth-of-type(3n+3) {background-color: #ffffff;}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is *obvious* that you get all the colors same because `left-inner-container` is always the `first-child` of its *parent container*.

I propose to take your `link-row` container to target the `nth-of-type` selector. See a simplified html-CSS demo below:

```css
.link-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  background: #ddd;
}

.left-inner-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: #450037;
}

.link-row:nth-of-type(3n+1) .left-inner-container {
  background-color: #ff5e39;
}

.link-row:nth-of-type(3n+2) .left-inner-container {
  background-color: #00d2d1;
}

.link-row:nth-of-type(3n+3) .left-inner-container {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="link-row">
    <div class="link-row-header-container">
      <div class="header-name">header</div>
      <div class="header-info">info</div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container">
      <div class="left-inner-container">left</div>
      <div class="right-inner-container">right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-row-footer-container">
      <span> footer stuff </span>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="link-row">
    <div class="link-row-header-container">
      <div class="header-name">header</div>
      <div class="header-info">info</div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container">
      <div class="left-inner-container">left</div>
      <div class="right-inner-container">right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-row-footer-container">
      <span> footer stuff </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="link-row">
    <div class="link-row-header-container">
      <div class="header-name">header</div>
      <div class="header-info">info</div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container">
      <div class="left-inner-container">left</div>
      <div class="right-inner-container">right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-row-footer-container">
      <span> footer stuff </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="link-row">
    <div class="link-row-header-container">
      <div class="header-name">header</div>
      <div class="header-info">info</div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container">
      <div class="left-inner-container">left</div>
      <div class="right-inner-container">right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-row-footer-container">
      <span> footer stuff </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="link-row">
    <div class="link-row-header-container">
      <div class="header-name">header</div>
      <div class="header-info">info</div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container">
      <div class="left-inner-container">left</div>
      <div class="right-inner-container">right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-row-footer-container">
      <span> footer stuff </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Now I feel pretty dumb. Misunderstood a fundamental to how the selector worked and had no idea you could select by class after the nth-child declaration so I must be missing a core CSS syntax concept as well. Time to do some reading. This solution worked, so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just update the below CSS will resolve your issue. Thanks

```
.left-inner-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: #450037;
  background-color: #ff5e39;
}

.left-inner-container:nth-child(2) {background-color: #00d2d1;}
.left-inner-container:nth-child(3) {background-color: #ffffff;}
```